# Php return boolean

Tags: php

Here is an example of what I am trying to understand:

```
return (@mysql_query($sql)) ? true:false;
```

I want to return either true or false if this line is executed successfully:

```
$this->sql->execute();
```

Can someone explain me how this *if like* thing works and how can I use it with my line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement executes the `mysql_query()` call and if it was successful, returns the boolean `TRUE` from the function in which it resides. If the SQL query fails, it returns boolean `FALSE`.

Whether or not you can use this construct depends on if you expect your `execute()` call to return a result set (in a `SELECT` statement) or if it is used for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`.  If you attempt this with a `SELECT` statement, you would not be able to fetch your result rows with this statement.

If it is only for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`, you may be able to do

```
return $this->sql->execute() ? true : false;
```

**However**, we still can't be sure this will work because you have not posted the contents of the class from which `execute()` is called.

The ternary operator is used to assign or return one value or another based on the result of a condition.

```
$returned_or_assigned_value = condition ? true_return_val : false_return_val;
```

Ternary operations are very commonly used to assign one of two values to a variable.  Using them in a return statement is a similar operation, if you think of the variable assignee as the function's return.

Comment: In case of SELECT statement you will get resource object that will be correspond TRUE value. But you will not be able to check does SELECT return values or no, just SQL syntax.

Comment: It's Doctrine ORM's query execute() method.